# Linux Centos 7, Google Chrome error: Missing X server or $DISPLAY / The platform failed to initialize. Exiting

Tags: google-chrome, centos7

I have latest google install (google-chrome-stable-117.0.5938.132-1.x86_64),

xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.20.4-23.el7_9.x86_64

mesa-libgbm-18.3.4-12.el7_9.x86_64

but Google-chrome doesn't start anyway. I run it as google-chrome --no-sandbox

eand I get this error set:

[image]

Then I do: export DISPLAY=:99

and I try to run google as above, but I get:

[image]

And gogole-chrome never starts.
Please help, I am quite new to Centos.
Thank you very much.